# Perl Replace Simplify

Tags: regex, perl

I was working on some string parsing and I was wondering if there was a way to replace these 11 lines with one, I know I can use \d to select a digit, but is there a way to use that same digit in the replace string?

Thanks ahead of time

```
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?-/:"-/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?1/:"1/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?2/:"2/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?3/:"3/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?4/:"4/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?5/:"5/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?6/:"6/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?7/:"7/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?8/:"8/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?9/:"9/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?0/:"0/g;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?([-\d])/:"$1/g;
```

The parentheses create a "capture group", and `$1` in the replacement pattern means the contents of the 1st capture group.

Comment: Thank you so much, so if there was more than one group captured could i use $2..$3..$n?

Comment: Exactly. Details in [`perldoc -f perlretut`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlretut.pod#Extracting-matches)

Comment: Thanks! This really helped, it turned my 51 lines of replacing to 5!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a capturing group and use that in the replacement using `$1`

```
:\s?([0-9-])
```

Your code could look like:

```
$msgPayload =~ s/:\s?([0-9-])/:"$1/g
```